# Does partial page caching exist outside of asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I use partial page caching with ASP.NET.  I find it to be particularly helpful with large volume sites, where I need only certain sections of a page to cache.

Do other web application platforms have this type of technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually called "fragment caching", and it's baked in to most web frameworks.

Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html

Django: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

Merb: http://merbivore.com/documentation/current/doc/rdoc/merb-cache/index.html

Zend: http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html#zend.cache.frontends.output

CakePHP: http://book.cakephp.org/view/156/Caching